# How can I match a single condition in Rust; 'match', 'if matches!', or 'if let'?

Tags: rust

I want to check a condition that depends only on its structure (but not the actual values it holds), and do something in either case. I can think of three ways do this: with `match`, `if let`, or `if matches!`. I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks to any of these or if they are effectively equivalent.

Am I safe to use any of these or are there known drawbacks that I might run into with one or more of these? Is there a fourth way that I haven't thought of?

```
match self.context.get(s) {
    Some(Bound::Function(_, _)) => Err("Parse Error".to_string())
    _ => {
        self.context.insert(s.clone(), ...);
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

```
if let Some(Bound::Function(_, _)) = self.context.get(s) {
    Err("Parse Error".to_string())
}
else {
    self.context.insert(s.clone(), ...);
    Ok(None)
}
```

```
if matches!(self.context.get(s), Some(Bound::Function(_, _))) {
    Err("Parse Error".to_string())
}
else {
    self.context.insert(s.clone(), ...);
    Ok(None)
}
```

Comment: You would need to benchmark to be sure, but I suspect that performance-wise the best solution would use the [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API: https://paste.chapril.org/?b0a699352e8efade#4FMmC6T9MpSfuUjvZrVyppY6SR9h6MEroAduaJt7xPmV

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418589/is-this-question-opinion-based).

Answer (score 0):

Your three solutions are equivalent. As of today they even compile to the same machine code: https://godbolt.org/z/d4acvY5G3

Performance-wise, you would need to benchmark but I suspect that the fastest would be to use the [`entry` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry). Something along the lines of:

```
match self.context.entry (s) {
   Entry::Occupied (_) => Err("Parse Error".to_string()),
   Entry::Vacant (e) => {
      e.insert (Bound::Number(evaluate(&self.context, parseadd(tokens))?));
      Ok (None)
   }
}
```

Note that depending on the rest of your code, this solution might require to always clone `s` whereas yours don't clone it if the entry already exists. However:

- Your solutions only avoid cloning when an error occurs, which should be a rare occurrence and less performance-sensitive than the non-error case.
- If performance is really an issue, it would probably be best to avoid cloning altogether if possible (but that depends on where `s` comes from).
- As with all performance-related questions, you should measure it *in your environment* to see if it brings any significant improvement (and you should only try to improve it after you have shown that it is a performance bottleneck for your application).

Comment: I'm not too concerned about performance, I'm more concerned about which one of these best follows the conventions of the language.

Comment: @TheZachMan You can't really ask about conventions here because those are opinion-based, and Stack Overflow does not allow opinion-based questions. Focus on the real, objective, achievable problem you are concerned with instead.